# NIC Teaming HP Server running Win2003

Tags: bonding, nic

I'm new to server NIC TEaming. I have a HP ProLiant DL360 G4p running Win2003 with 2 NICs , only one is currently active. I'd like to activate the 2nd NIC connected (in a active/passive state) to a 2nd switch  with only one IP address and ideally only one mac layer address. The 1st switch is a Cisco 2960G and the 2nd is a Cisco C3560G. There are VLANS, RSTP and PAGP in use already.

Can someone give me an idea, in broad terms , of what technology/protocols I should be investigating (HSRP, SLB/TLB Teaming etc.) ? I can provide more info if needed.

Thanks, Colm.

Answer (score 1):

This is so much simpler than you think, just make sure that both ports on each switch are configured as similarly as possible then run the HP Proliant Support Pack, reboot and then just use the HP NIC tools to bind both NICs to create a single vNIC - configure IP etc. on that vNIC, reboot and you should be away!

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the server? To provide routing or are you simply trying to access the server from two separate networks?  For routing you would want to look at RRAS.  Simply accessing the server from two networks only requires that you give the second NIC an IP on that network.

Comment: In this case it is a DC only, no other function . Eventually, I'd like to do the same with my exchange server (not clustered) . I'm looking for basic fault tolerance on the NIC, switch and IP levels so only one IP address on 2 NICs, each one on a difference switch.